# What does "loading" page actually load

Tags: android

Many heavy games have a loading splash screen before the game starts. I wonder, what does a load page actually load (so maybe I can use such an optimization in my app)? Are they loading images? If they are then memory will run out quickly.

Thank you

Comment: You'd probably have to ask each development team for each game that had a splash screen to get "the right answer." Good guess, though, is that they load what they need to start playing the game.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splash_screen lists alot of purposes. First of all you load everything that you don't want to be loaded at runtime, e.g. that would make your game lag.

Comment: Loading engine, loading resources, loading connection to server(s), loading lots. You can load whatever you need.

Comment: Why would you load pictures? you pretty much set the view to the image using resource ID. Loading pictures into memory will get into out of memory

Comment: But you need to balance memory versus game play. If loading a needed image takes too long, the game becomes less usable and, therefore, less fun. Having things ready when needed, within reason, is one method of ensuring a good experience. Always test; if game play is enhanced by loading the resources, do it. If not, then load resources as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading pics, deserializing data, requesting data from db... it depends on what app actually do.

Comment: Why would you load pictures? you pretty much set the view to the image using resource ID. Loading pictures into memory will get into out of memory